# Node/Express - Good approach to secure communication between client/server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, encryption

I'm building a backend API with Node/Express, which get the data from a MongoDB. The front will be written in React.

I would like to secure the communication client/server, but I don't know how I have to think about the process.

I see many tutorial about `passport` or `JWT`, but this is good for an user authentication.

I don't know if creating a token for every request based on the time (for example) is a good approach or it's too consuming for a web app.

But my goal is to secure the data because even if the API is private you can easily find out the route and try to figure it out how to fake request with Postman or something else to scrap the data.

Comment: On a semi-related note, I think enabling HTTPS is the first step (you can get free certificates from [LetsEncrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/)), in addition to a secure, tried and true user/session authentication mechanism. Also, you will want to read up on the information on the [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page) site for guarding against common attacks such as XSS, CSRF, etc.

Comment: Thank you ! I have enabled the middleware named `helmet` which handle already a bunch of attack like XSS i think :
https://www.npmjs.com/package/helmet

I will look at your link. Merci !

I will use HTTPS for sure and I know about LetsEncrypt (named cerbot I think now) because I used it for my personal website. But I'm still in dev mode (localhost) so I will do it when the real server will be up. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The accepted standard is to use a fixed API KEY. This peace of info should be a randomly generated string that you send in each request in the header. Your server has to check the HTTP request each time to see if the API KEY is present in the header, and if it is, then it has to check against the stored value in the environment variable (never store the API KEY in code).

If the API KEY gets compromised, then you can easily update the env variable, and you are good again.

Now, this solution will be pointless without a HTTPS connection, because anyone will be able to sniff the traffic and see the API KEY. An encrypted connection is a must in this case.

This approach is used by virtually every company that has a public API: Twitter, Facebook, Twilio, Google etc.

Google for example has an extra step where they give you a token that will expire, but this will be an over kill in your case: at least in the beginning.

The following code is an example of my implementation of a API KEY check

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {

    //
    //  1. Check if the APIKey is present
    //
    if(!req.headers.authorization)
    {
        return res.status(400).json(
            {
                message: "Missing APIKey.",
                description: "Unable to find the APIKey"
            }
        );
    }

    //
    //  2. Remove Basic from the beginning of the string
    //
    let noBasic = req.headers.authorization.replace('Basic ', '');

    //
    //  3. Convert from base64 to string
    //
    let b64toString = new Buffer(noBasic, 'base64').toString("utf8");

    //
    //  4. Remove the colon from the end of the string
    //
    let userAPIKey = b64toString.replace(':', '');

    //
    //  5. Check if the APIKey matches the one on the server side.
    //
    if(userAPIKey != process.env.API_KEY)
    {
        return res.status(400).json(
            {
                message: "APIKey don't match",
                description: "Make sure what you are sending is what is in your server."
            }
        );
    }

    //
    //  -> Go to the next stage
    //
    next()

});
```

You can check the whole file with the whole implementation [hear](https://github.com/davidgatti/What-Is-My-IP/blob/v0.1.0/server/app.js#L36).

Comment: Thank you, it's really clear now. Just 2 questions. 
1) Do you have to setup something specific to handle HTTPS client/server side (except the certificat on the server side). Do I have to setup nginx ?

2) how do you manage the env.API_KEY. It's simply an env variable in the system like I would set `export EDITOR=emacs`for example ? Also how do I manage client side ? The same code but reverse (encoding the string before sending it ?). Thanks

Comment: Lots of question :) since the comment section has limited char, I'll answer each question in a separated comment.

Comment: **HTTPS**: there are many ways to do it, and it all depends where are you going to host your app. If you host it on Heroku, you don't have to do anything on your side, you enable SSL on their side, thus you have to google how to do it there. If you shot e it yourself, you can check my article hear how to add SSL, which is trivial: https://github.com/davidgatti/IoT-Raw-Sockets-Examples/tree/master/Templates/NodeJS/tls. Anything else it depends on you :)

Comment: **Managing Keys**: this again depends where are you hosting and how are you running the server. If you are going to run the app on Heroku, then you'll have to use Foreman, check this module https://www.npmjs.com/package/foreman. It explains in detail how to set up everything including the env variables. You would like to use PM2, then the use a process.json file, just read the documentation on that file to understand how to setup everything

Comment: **Client code**: when you are going to make a API request, you are going to use probably Unrest or something similar. In this case you can use the `Request.auth` method, or you can write the header yourself: `.header('authorization', 'Basic ' + SERVICE_API_KEY)`. Unrest will convert the API KEY in Base64 automatically for you. I also recommend the site http://requestb.in to test your request if something goes wrong :)

Comment: Nice I will work on that.
You can also edit the primary post to give a full response (and also be a good tutorial for someone who is gonna look also for an answer ;) ).
Thank you for the time you spend to give me all this advice. i appreciate it ! Cheers !!!

Comment: No worries, I'm glad I could point you in the right direction :) Best.

Answer (score 2):

As I just finished the auth part of my **AngularJS** application. The answer will be **JWT** and **Passport**, you should use the great technologies to protect your data / API.

If you use the JWT library, it will help you hold the http heads for authorization.

Some of the code I used:

app.js

```
var jwt = require('express-jwt');

var auth = jwt({
    secret: config.jwt.secret,
    userProperty: 'payload'
});

app.use('/api/secret', auth, apiSecretRoutes);
```

login.js

```
module.exports.login = function (req, res) {
    if (!req.body.username || !req.body.password) {
        return tools.sendJSONresponse(res, 400, {
            message: 'All fields required!'
        });
    }

    passport.authenticate('local', function (err, user, info) {
        var token;
        if (err) {
            return tools.sendJSONresponse(res, 404, err);
        }

        if (user) {
            token = user.generateJwt();
            return tools.sendJSONresponse(res, 200, {
                ok: true,
                message: 'welcome ' + user.name,
                token: token
            });
        } else {
            return tools.sendJSONresponse(res, 400, info);
        }
    })(req, res);
};
```

user.js

```
userSchema.methods.generateJwt = function() {
    var expiryDays = 1;
    var expiry = new Date();
    expiry.setDate(expiry.getDate() + expiryDays);

    return jwt.sign({
        _id: this._id,
        username: this.username,
        name: this.name,
        exp: parseInt(expiry.getTime() / 1000)
    }, config.jwt.secret);
};
```

More Refs:

- https://thinkster.io/angularjs-jwt-auth
- http://devdactic.com/restful-api-user-authentication-1/
- http://devdactic.com/restful-api-user-authentication-2/
- http://jwt.io
- https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt

Comment: Thank you. But I don't need user authentification with a username and password. It's more an internal API where I want to secure the request, and the data. Nothing about auth an user to keep track of his use of my app nor to denied access to some part of the app. But thank by the way because I gonna need a way to use this kind of auth sooner or later ;)